# animate component entering the DOM in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation

being new to React, makes it hard for me to understand how to animate elements in React. Is there a simple way to do it without using react-transition-group? Let's say i have this code:

```
class CategoriesList extends Component{ 
  renderList(){
     return this.props.categories.map((category) => {
       return(
         <div
           key={category.title}
           className="button">
           {category.title}
         </div>
       )
     })
   }               
  render(){
    return (
      <div className= 'container'>
        {this.renderList()}
      </div>
      )
   }}
```

Where renderList() is a method which renders a list of some div's based on props. How could i animate the container div to fade in when the CategoriesList component is rendered?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount () {
    
    dynamics.animate(this.refs.a, {
      translateX: 150,
      opacity: 1
    }, {
      type: dynamics.spring,
      frequency: 200,
      friction: 200,
      duration: 1500
    })
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div ref="a" style={{
        padding: 10,
        background: 'tomato',
        color: 'white',
        width: 200,
        fontFamily: 'Helvetica'
      }}>
        Animating Div
      </div>
    )
  }
}



ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.querySelector('#root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dynamics.js/1.1.5/dynamics.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

I've used dynamics.js here to animate.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this easily using the React lifecycle and basic CSS.

CSS:

```
.container {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 200ms opacity ease-in-out;
}
```

React:

```
  class CategoriesList extends Component{ 
  ...
  componentDidMount() {
    this.refs.container.style.opacity = 1;
  }
  ...
  render(){
    return (
      <div className= 'container' ref="container">
        {this.renderList()}
      </div>
      )
   }}
```

The React lifecycle is where the magic happens. [Check out the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html) to learn more. Also note the usage of the ref attribute for accessing the container div node. You can do a lot with that as well, but make sure you only attempt this after your component is rendered.